# Preload images with Isotope and Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope

### Isotope with Bootstrap 3 image load issue

I have a problem with a template that I'm developing based on Bootstrap 3. I have some portfolio pages where I used isotope, it works fine  but when the page loads there's always an annoying "click" with a picture at the top of the screen before the page load is complete. I tried the methods recommended by Desandro in his forum and the solutions posted on stackoverflow, but have not been able to adapt.
This is the code I used:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('.example');

  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector : '.item'
    });
  });
var $container = $('.example'),
    colWidth = function () {
        var w = $container.width(), 
            columnNum = 1,
            columnWidth = 0;
        if (w > 1200) {
            columnNum  = 4;
        } else if (w > 900) {
            columnNum  = 3;
        } else if (w > 600) {
            columnNum  = 3;
        } else if (w > 300) {
            columnNum  = 1;
        }
        columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
        $container.find('.item').each(function() {
            var $item = $(this),
                multiplier_w = $item.attr('class').match(/item-w(\d)/),
                multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/item-h(\d)/),
                width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-4 : columnWidth-4,
                height = multiplier_h ? columnWidth*multiplier_h[1]*0.5-4 : columnWidth*0.5-4;
            $item.css({
                width: width,
                height: height
            });
        });
        return columnWidth;
    },
    isotope = function () {
        $container.isotope({
            resizable: false,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colWidth(),
                gutterWidth: 4
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
 </script>
```

And this is the live preview: http://skylightthailand.com/morters_morters/portfolio_2columns.html

Comment: You have the base istope css in your file? The containers don't appear to clear.

Comment: It's based on the original one, but it's modified with the on hover effect with link and lightbox buttons

Comment: I would post the minimal amount of code, css, & html in JSBin then you get people interested. I've never encountered this before and I've been using masonry isotope for  a long time.

Comment: Yes the code it's too messy, I will try another approach thanks